# How to connect to otrs MySQL database using mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, database, otrs

We have a Linux Vm which is running our OTRS. I have found the kernel file which has the database configuration details. In there the host name is listed as local host.

I tried using the server IP address along with the database username that is there; however I cannot seem to connect.

I also cannot find the port that is utilized. How do I connect to the database on mysqlworkbench,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe server doesn't allow remote connections to the DB or user used by OTRS is only a local user? 
If this is true you've got two options:

- Create user that is allowed to login remotelyCreate user that is allowed to login remotely
- Create user that is allowed to login remotely
  Use *Standart (TCP/IP) over SSH* as connection method in MySQL workbench. This option allows to first connect over SSH to the server and than connect to the DB as local user